# How do I Write R code to find the number of rows in a data set, & the names of the columns and the unique values of landcover classes in this dataset

Tags: r

I have a dataset titled “landcover.csv” on the area of land (the variable Area) covered by different land cover classes (the variable Class) in Brazil and Canada in the years 2008 and 2018.

I set working directory, then i import dataset to R
library(tidyverse)
land = read_csv('landcover.csv')

**Question 1: Write R code to find the number of rows and the names of the columns in this dataset.**
**Question 2: Write R code to find the unique values of landcover classes in this dataset.**

I have tried the code below but not sure it's giving an unexpected error.

> > nrow(landcover)
> > Error: unexpected '>' in ">"
>
> > colnames(landcover)
> > Error: unexpected '>' in ">"
>
> > unique(landcover)
> > Error: unexpected '>' in ">"
> > unique(landcover)
> > Error: unexpected '>' in ">"

**Question 3: Consider only the year 2018.  Use R to find the total area of land of each Country.  Also write a dplyr pipe to construct a summary table giving the total area for each land cover class, given in decreasing order of area.  Include both R code and output in your answer.**

**Question 4: (d)   We wish to investigate the change in land cover in each country between 2008 and 2018.  Firstly, explain what the R code given below produces.  Secondly, add further R code to reproduce the graphical plot below as accurately as possible.  Thirdly, give one conclusion that you can draw from the graphical plot.  Include both explanation and R code in your answer.**

land %>%
pivot_wider(names_from=Year, values_from=Area) %>%
rename(year2018=`2018`, year2008=`2008`)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. `dput(head(land))`, then copy resulting `structure(....)`, here at bottom as Data: using ``` above and below  your structure``` so we can help better.

Comment: The first errors seem to come from the fact that you have 'copy-paste'd solutions and kept the prompt charcater ">" in the process.... Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and ask one precise question in one post, do not copy-past your homework here!!!

Comment: Also, it looks like you stored the data in `land` but then later you used `landcover`

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't have access to your data, I'll create a small dataset to try and answer your questions:

```r
library(tidyverse)
df <- tibble(
  "id" = c(1:5),
  "name" = c("Patrick","Josh","Ana","Jasmine","Jonathan"),
  "sex" = c("Male","Male","Female","Female","Male"),
  "age" = c(18,22,25,28,12)
)


# A tibble: 5 × 4
     id name     sex      age
  <int> <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 Patrick  Male      18
2     2 Josh     Male      22
3     3 Ana      Female    25
4     4 Jasmine  Female    28
5     5 Jonathan Male      12
```

Concerning your first question, I'd recommend using the `str()` function:

```r
str(df)

tibble [5 × 4] (S3: tbl_df/tbl/data.frame)
 $ id  : int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
 $ name: chr [1:5] "Patrick" "Josh" "Ana" "Jasmine" ...
 $ sex : chr [1:5] "Male" "Male" "Female" "Female" ...
 $ age : num [1:5] 18 22 25 28 12
```

You can see from the print that you have a `tibble` (`dataframe` alternative), with 5 rows and 4 columns. Each row in the console print gives you the name of a column, the type of column (int, chr, num, etc.) and list the first couple of observations.

Regarding your second question, I will assume that my "sex" column resembles your "classes" column:

```r
df %>%
  count(sex, sort = TRUE, name = "count")


# A tibble: 2 × 2
  sex    count
  <chr>  <int>
1 Male       3
2 Female     2
```

Using `count()` you can see the unique values in the "sex" column and how many times they appear. Suppose you just want a list of the unique values you could also:

```r
df %>%
  distinct(sex)

# A tibble: 2 × 1
  sex   
  <chr> 
1 Male  
2 Female
```

The rest of the question are difficult to answer without access to the data.

Generally speaking, it would be nice to provide some sort of sample data to help people answer your questions.

Regarding the errors you get in your code in question 1, it looks to me like when you read the file, there's some sort of formatting error going on. It would help if you posted some of your code and posted the output of a `print()`. Following my example:

```r
print(df)

# A tibble: 5 × 4
     id name     sex      age
  <int> <chr>    <chr>  <dbl>
1     1 Patrick  Male      18
2     2 Josh     Male      22
3     3 Ana      Female    25
4     4 Jasmine  Female    28
5     5 Jonathan Male      12
```

Comment: Thank you. I could not attach the csv file to the question. To clarify, Tibble is the title of your data right?

Comment: You don't need to attach the whole file, but you could at least use the ```print()``` function to show us your output, else it's really difficult to get what exactly is wrong.
Tibble is a type of dataframe, it's part of the tidyverse.